# QTableWidget - QMenu Context Menu - AddAction slots not calling functions

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu, qtablewidget, qmenu

I'm trying to call a function via a context menu embedded inside of a QTablewidget. It does not call the function in the slot. Could I be missing something ? The context menus do appear but clicking does nothing.

```
    QMenu *contextMenu = new QMenu;
    QModelIndex cell = ui->tableWidget->indexAt(pos);

    if(cell.isValid())

    {
            contextMenu->addAction("Burn Case", this, SLOT(burnCase()));

            contextMenu->addAction("Export Case", this, SLOT(exportCase(cell.row())));

            contextMenu->addAction("Delete Case", this, SLOT(deleteCase(cell.row())));

            contextMenu->exec(ui->tableWidget->mapToGlobal(pos));
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

The slot without a parameter being passed appears to be working, but not the ones with parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SLOT(exportCase(cell.row())))` is not valid `connect` argument. The string passed in `SLOT()` macro must contain the slot's name and its argument types. You can't pass argument values directly. So, if your slot accepts `int` argument, the statement would be `SLOT(exportCase(int))`.

More than that, you can't connect a signal to a slot with mismatching arguments. `QMenu::addAction` connects your slot to the `QAction::triggered(bool)` signal. So you can only use a slot with no arguments or a slot with a single `bool` argument.

Any run-time `connect` issues can be detected using return value of `connect()`. You'd better check it if you're experiencing some issues. Also, Qt Creator's autocomplete could help you to use `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros.

See also [connect documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qobject.html#connect).